# execute an action and request a signature if needed

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

I am trying to develop a component where a signature is requiered from a user to complete a certain operation here is the sequence:

1. User clicks on a commandButton or commandLink.
2. A popup opens requesting the user to enter the username/password
3. If the user enters the correct username/password the original action is executed.
4. If the user enters the wrong username/password or clicks the cancel button nothing happens.
5. Finally when the action is really executed the signature information should be available.

Note: the solution should be a composite component that should have the following structure:

```
<myCC:confirm action="#{testMB.delete}" singatureType="deleteObject"/>
```

What I did to implement this behavior is:

1. Created a view scoped managed bean **SignatureMB** to handle the signature with the properties (username, password, and signatureType)
2. Created a request scoped managed bean **#{testMB}** with a managed property mapped to the **#{signatureMB}**
3. in my composite component **myCC:confirm** I created two links an outputLink that will open a popup with the signature form, the second is a hidden commandLink that will contain the real action to submit i.e. **#{testMB.delete}**
4. The signature form is posted and if the username/password are correct the popup will close itself and trigger the click event of the hidden commandLink.
5. Finally in the **#{testMB.delete}** I will have the signature information, and be able to process the information and when done I will reset the values in the **signatureMB**.

What do you think about this implementation? do you think there is a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a reasonable implementation and a good starting point.

You will need an addition step 4a to process the incorrect username/password logic

Answer (score 0):

The hidden link part is the "loose link :-)" On successful authentication you can invoke delete automatically, would the user really need to click again to delete ? Also the link can it be rendered dynamically ?

Comment: What do you mean by invoke the delete automatically? for now I am doing it by triggering the onclick event of the hidden commandLink.

I didn't mention that the user have to click the delete again! and finally what link should be rendered dynamically? could you please be more clear?

Comment: My oversight in assuming that "the user had to call delete again" I take that back. That was also the reason to suggest that "Delete link" had to be rendered dynamically. I was hoping that the delete function could be called from the server side instead of invoking from the client side.

Comment: It is a composite component that will be reused in the whole project, in my example its a delete action but it could be anything else.